# Change of variable ,Contour Integration

Tags: complex-analysis

I know that solving the integral

$I=\int\limits_C\frac{1}{z}dz       $ where $C:|z|=1$

is easy, we can simply write $ I=\int\limits_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{e^{it}}ie^{it}dt$$ =i\int\limits_0^{2\pi}dt$ $=2i\pi$

My question is why we can not complete from this step $ I=\int\limits_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{e^{it}}ie^{it}dt$ by taking a change variable $u= e^{it}$ this way we will get while changing the boundaries for $t=0$, $u=1$ and for $t=2\pi$, $u=1$

so what is wrong in this thinking

Comment: Look at the conditions of the [Cauchy integral theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy's_integral_theorem#Discussion). You can take the principal value of the logarithm and obtain
$$\int_{|z| = 1} \frac {dz} z =
\lim_{\epsilon \downarrow 0}
 \ln z \bigg\rvert_{z = -1 - i \epsilon}^{-1 + i \epsilon}$$
but not
$$\int_{|z| = 1} \frac {dz} z =
\ln z \bigg\rvert_{z = -1}^{-1}.$$

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because all that you're doing is reversing the change of variables that you did in the first place! In particular, you are winding around the origin one time, and there is a pole here, so the integral's value is reflecting that. If you want to know more about this topic, you can read about the *argument principle* (note that the function $f(z)=z$ has a single zero at $z=0$, which is bounded inside your contour).